# Optimizing parquet files in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, parquet

I have a large computational job in pyspark that can output to a parquet format reasonably quickly, but generates thousands of ~3Mb files across N partitions (where N is known). I know that I can repartition the data across those partitions before writing, but the shuffle job from ~2000 nodes takes seemingly forever. Given this, I have a two-part question:

1. Will it be better to repartition and then write to parquet in a single step, or write to parquet then reingest and rewrite to parquet again, combining the small files? Essentially, this performs a parquet optimization step at the end. Note that I'm not worried about storage space.
2. If I take the route of reingesting and rewriting, is the following the best way of doing this operation?

```py
df.repartition(N, 'partition_name').write.partitionBy('partition_name').saveAsTable(...)
```

It seems that the repartition command introduces another slow shuffle operation, which really shouldn't be necessary, given that the data is already partitioned.

Comment: If u have a lot of small files/ partitions and u would like to create create lesser partitions so spark could parallelize better , u should use coalesce as it reduces number of partitions into chunkier partitions without inducing a shuffle

Comment: The number of partitions is fixed - I'm getting a lot of little files in a single partition. I'd just like to merge all those little files into one big file in that partition.